# Some computer has TPM, is it in the motherboard?

Tags: computer-building

I want to buy high end computer with TPM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module

Where is this TPM chip put? In CPU? In mother board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trusted Platform Modules ([TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)) are put on the motherboard of a computer by the manufacturer.

As far as I know, there are no add-in TPMs on PCI cards or other add-on boards.

EDIT:  I do want to add that there are motherboards with *slots* for TPMs, but the TPM itself is sold separately.

[image]

Comment: It would be surprising to see a TPM add-in for a motherboard that's not designed for that module. One of the functions of TPM is remote attestation (validating the hardware present), and you can't do that from a PCI-e card. It justs sees one PCI-e bus.